# Cómo acceder a un objeto desde un controlador laravel

Tags: laravel, json, laravel-8

estoy muy verde con el manejo de objetos json. En mi base de datos pude guardar en el formato json de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo se ve en **content** tengo un json.

Desde el controlador realizo el siguiente foreach

```
foreach($orders as $item){
        $contenido = $item->content;
    }

dd($contenido);
```

Y me devuelve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy buscando la forma de acceder al valor **vendedor_user_id**

Intente realizando:

dd($contenido->options->vendedor_user_id);

Y recibo el error: Trying to get property 'options' of non-object.

Probé con un foreach y tampoco funciona.

¿Como es la manera de acceder a la propiedad de forma específica?

Comment: Agrega la consulta que realizas por favor

Comment: Hola Betam al final puse la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

**Hola Primero que todo el campo de vendedor_Id, es nulo por lo que no hay ningún dato, también debes tener una relación en las tablas para que traiga las llaves foráneas, te enviare un ejemplo de cómo debe ser todo **

**tabla a la que seran asignados los campos**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('nombre_tabla', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('status');
        $table->text('comision');
        $table->string('total');
        $table->foreignId('Vendedor_id')->references('id')->on('vendedor')->coment('Vendedor');
        $table->timestamps();
        
    });
}
```

**relaciones vendedor.php**

```
public function ventas()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ventas::class);
}
```

**controller de ventas**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //validacion campos
    $data = request()->validate([
        'status' => 'required',
        'comision' => 'required',
        'total' => 'required',

    ]);

    //Insertar con modelo
    auth()->user()->publicaciones()->create([
        'status' => $data['status'],
        'comision' => $data['comision'],
        'total' => $data['total'],
        
    ]);
    
}
```

**En el método store del controller pasas los datos a la vista del usuario por medio del foreach  para acceder al campo que quieres  **

```
public function show(Ventas $ventas)
{
   


    
   $data = Comentarios::all();
   foreach ($data as $valores) {
      dd($valores->user_id); 
   }
   


   
    
    
    
   
}
```

Comment: Hola Jesus, gracias por tu respuesta. vendedor_user_id no es nulo. Mi problema se encuentra en la forma de recuperar el valor de vendedor_user_id llego a recuperar todos los valores que hay en el json pero dentro dle json tengo la propiedad vendedor_user_id y ahí no logro recuperar el valor, pero en la base de datos está correctamente. Necesito ese valor para validar una vista.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas conocer el key del json, en este caso es el valor numérico y separarlo

```
foreach($orders as $item){
    if ($contenido = $item->content) {
        foreach($contenido as $key => $json) {
            dd($json->vendedor_user_id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Jonathan justamente busco hacer algo así como indicas, pero recibo el error Invalid argument supplied for foreach() y en vendedor_user_id si tengo el dato que deseo obtener. Que puede estar mal? gracias!!

Comment: Has un dump($contenido) dentro del primer for para ver que tipo de dato obtienes